# How to catch event from CLR on C++

Tags: .net, c++, clr, command-line-interface

I'm running simple dialog on CLR where I fill some textBoxes and press push, So but I need to know when I pressed push.

Here is how I run dialog :

```
void CFloBossOPCDlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
    NewBoi ^ nb = gcnew NewBoi();
    nb->Show();
```

I can't declare nb as global variable and even I can't declare nb as part of CFloBossOPCDlg so how can I override close event to understand when I need to get filled textboxes ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gcroot to declare handles in native types.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you ! That is looking like solution. Another little question if I can override OnClose like this : nb.FormClosed += (s, ex) =>

Comment: Please post that as a new question

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler for the `Closed` event on the `nb` object.